# nonlinear diffusion for image processing

Tags: numerical-methods

Can you help me solve this problem? The problem lies in the following:
Problem: nonlinear diffusion for image processing:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RISX9.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4OL.png)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLC7T.png)

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oogB4.png)

[img5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8tYn.png)

[img6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXrct.png)

[img7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0r8d.png)

k is a user-defined parameter.

a) write method of lines for the problem above.

b) RK method according to the following Butcher's table.
[Butcher's table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCnRW.png)

c) A-stability condition of the method.

Can you help me solve this?

I tried and solved solution b) but I couldn't understand how to solve other parts.

Comment: The method is part of Fehlbergs embedded 2(3) method. Or more generally a 3rd order method based on the 2nd order Heun method and Simpson quadrature rule. // The equation is a generalized heat equation `dI/dt = div(D*grad(I))` with `D=g(norm(grad(I)))`. // The last two boundary conditions have the wrong variable. // The stability of the RK method is the same as for any other minimal explicit 3rd order RK method, see https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf for a collection of them.